# How to get the column letter of the first non blank cell of a range in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, cell, nonblank

I need to get the column letter of the first non-blank cell of a range. This range is basically a part of a row like.

Example:
Range = A2:G2
First non blank cell is on F2 cell.
Need to get 'F' and store it in a String variable.
What is the most efficient way to get this?

Thanks

Comment: It's perfectly possible, but where are you going to use it for if I may ask? Maybe there is a much cleaner way of doing things for what you intend to do with the `"F"`?

Comment: ^^^ My guess is that it'll be easier to work with the column index than the column letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub columnName()
    Dim mainRange As Range, cell As Range, columnName As String
    Set mainRange = Range("A2:G2")
    'Set mainRange = Selection
    For Each cell In mainRange.Cells
        If Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
            MsgBox Split(cell.Address, "$")(1)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get that column letter with a function:

```
Function firstBlankCol(rg As Range) As String
Dim x
    If rg(1) = "" Then
        x = rg(1).Address
    Else
        x = rg(1).End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).Address
    End If
    firstBlankCol = Split(x, "$")(1)
End Function
```

However, it is simpler, usually, to deal with the column number, and use that for the column argument of the `Cells` property.

```
Function firstBlankCol(rg As Range) As Long
Dim x
    If rg(1) = "" Then
        x = rg(1).Column
    Else
        x = rg(1).End(xlToRight).Column + 1
    End If
    firstBlankCol = x
End Function
```